# Issue upgrading from Umbraco 7.1.9 to 7.5.4

Tags: umbraco

I am having an issue when trying to upgrade either through Nuget or manually, after merging files, etc. I eventually get to a point whereby when I launch the website for the first time locally using http://localhost:81 (this works fine before the upgrade), I keep receiving the error message below.

The URL that is being redirected to is as follows:

http://localhost:81/install?redir=true&url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a81%2f

If I try to access the backend I also get the same message. I downloaded a copy of the Umbraco source and upon debugging can see in the file WebSecurity.cs of Umbraco.Web that the method IsAuthenticated() is showing null for the _httpContext.User.

Any ideas what the issue might be??

```
   [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Umbraco.Web.Security.WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated() +19
   Umbraco.Web.Security.WebSecurity.ValidateCurrentUser(Boolean throwExceptions) +17
   Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallController.Index() +142
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9644097
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same error when upgrading from umbraco 7.6.6 to any higher version. Tried 7.7.7, 7.6.11 and 7.6.7 and all show this error. Im using Structure map, but the solution @rybl sugested is not working for me. I was already using the default UmbracoApplication in my global asax. Did you maybe find a different solution for this? Thtnx

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the membership providers sections of the web.config file have merged properly. I think there were some user changes between those versions and some bits changed slightly? I'd also clear your cookies too, just in case, as sometimes I've had issues with UmbracoContext cookies after upgrades.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I double checked the membership providers section and everything is as it should be compared to the previous version and the new 7.5.4 version. I have also cleared my cookies and am also ensuring that I am using Incognito mode of Chrome but still the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and wanted to share my experience.

I found that the problem was that I am using a custom `UmbracoApplication` implementation to do dependency injection.

I believe the install process must use some dependency that the application does not normally use.

To work around the issue I changed my `Global.asax` to point to the default `UmbracoApplication` class. Then, after the database updated, I switched back to my custom class.

I'm sure there is a better way to fix this, but I wanted to document what I found in case someone has run into the same issue and is looking to get on the right track or for a quick fix.

My code is below:

```cs
<%-- Live App --%>
<%@ Application Inherits="Foo.WebsiteUmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>
<%-- For Umbraco DB Updates --%>
<%--<%@ Application Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>--%>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web;

namespace Foo
{
    public class WebsiteUmbracoApplication : UmbracoApplication
    {
        protected override void OnApplicationStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnApplicationStarted(sender, e);

            ConfigureDependencyInjection();
            ConfigureFormatters();
        }

        private static void ConfigureDependencyInjection()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.ConfiguredContainer;
            // MVC
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.UnityDependencyResolver(container));
            // Web API
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }

        private static void ConfigureFormatters()
        {
            var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
            formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);
        }
    }
}
```